# How to extract default namespace value from XML in Java or Xpath?

Tags: java, xpath-1.0

How do I extract default namespace value from XML in pure Java or Xpath in Java?

```
<root xmlns="http://root.com/v1" xmlns:other="http://other.com/v2">
   <childs>
   ...
</root>
```

I supose that the default xml namespace be: xmlns="http://root.com/v1"

But I can have other case where the same XML have a prefix like:

```
<x:root xmlns:x="http://root.com/v1" xmlns:other="http://other.com/v2">
   <x:childs>
   ...
</x:root>
```

I'd like just the value inside the "default" xmlns or the value inside xmlns:x that is being used by the root node. I need this value: **http://root.com/v1**

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The default namespace of `root` can be accessed with the XPath expression `namespace-uri(//*[local-name()="root"])` or `namespace-uri(/*)`. You'll find many code snippets for _xpath  java_

Answer (score 0):

As @mark61 commented out namespace-uri(/*) works fine. It ignore the prefix and always return the correct value from namespace.